# Implementing Events in Solidity (Remix)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, events, ethereumj

I have a test code on Remix and have been getting ParseError: Expected Primary Expression. The error happens in function Enquiry -- at event definition - line.

ParserError: Expected primary expression. event itemsListDisplay (bytes32 itemId, bytes32 itemDescription, bytes32 auctionStatus);
^

My reason for using event is to display a listing when the function is called by an approved participant. Each listing of items would be in a new line.

Any other suggestion for improved code style will also help.

Thanks. Below is the test code.

```
contract Request is MasterContract, 
ApprovedParticipantsContract, ApprovedItemsContract {


    function Enquiry (address _address) returns (bool flag) {

    event itemsListDisplay (bytes32 itemId, bytes32 itemDescription, bytes32 auctionStatus);        


    if (approvedParticipantsList[_address].isValue) {

        uint len = itemsList.keys.length;

        for (uint i = 0; i < len; i++)  {

            bytes32 myItemId = itemsList.keys[i].itemId;
            bytes32 myItemDescription = itemsList.keys[i].itemDescription;
            bytes32 myAuctionStatus = itemsList.keys[i].auctionStatus;

            itemsListDisplay(myItemId, myItemDescription, myAuctionStatus);


        }



        return true;

    }

    return false;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define the event log outside the function with/after your state variables. Then emit events as transactions happen.

```
contract Thing {

  event LogSomethingHappened(address sender, uint amount);

  function doSomething(uint qty) public returns(bool success) {
    LogSomethingHappened(msg.sender, qty);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.